# Loading body after flash animation completes

Tags: jquery, flash

I have a flash intro and I want the `<body>` to load right after the intro completes. How can I do that?

I don't want to redirect to a new URL after the animation completes, I want it to be on the same page.

Can I return a variable using actionscript3 which the jquery code catches, or can jQuery by itself detect when the animation completes ?

Comment: This isn't going to really help with your problem, but my advice is ditch the flash intro. It's not the late 90s anymore.

Comment: I agree. But my client wants the logo to appear gradually with a changing brightness, contrast, blurring (and maybe with flames too) etc and flash seems the only way.

Comment: If you're their developer you should advise them that that idea will lead to a MASSIVE bounce rate from their website and fewer visitors and therefore a lower ROI.

Comment: If you want to go down this route, why not just have two pages? One for the intro that redirects to the normal homepage once it finishes. That way, people might still be able to bookmark the real homepage without having to view the intro each time.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that part of your role as developer is education, and advisement against gauche ideas that not only will look extremely dated, but will likely turn off potential users, disrupt search engines, and not satisfy the core role of giving people a good experience relating to the client's brand.

Answer (score 1):

1) Flash intro: bad practice, especially as so many users are now surfing with devices that either don't come with Flash, or have disabled Flash entirely. Flash also completely destroys search engine results. #1 recommendation: learn how to do animation in HTML5/CSS3, if you absolutely must, but intro screens are incredibly harmful to usability in general. The only real excuse for using them is to provide some sort of feedback to users if you're trying to front-load assets (image sprites for a game, or data for a dashboard, for example).

2) You can't load Flash before the `<body>` of a page. It just doesn't work. However, given that, you could put together a structure like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="flashObj"><!-- object for Flash --></div>
    <div id="mainContent"><!-- rest of your page --></div>
</body>
```

Then you could call a javascript function from the end of your Flash animation (see http://www.kirupa.com/flash/calling_javascript_flash_using_as3.htm for a tutorial) using the ExternalInterface object, but note that there are several browsers that still have issues with that object, so your cross-platform usability goes even further down.

Essentially, in your html, you would have:

```
<style>
    #mainContent { display:none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function startMainContent(){
        var flash = document.getElementById("flashObj");
        var main  = document.getElementById("mainContent");
        if(flash && main){
            flash.style.display == "none";
            main.style.display == "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then in your ActionScript, after your animation completes, you would add something like:

```
ExternalInterface.call("startMainContent()");
```

Assuming ExternalInterface is working correctly, and you've followed Adobe's documentation for setting the proper flags in your `<object />` tag to enable access to Javascript from your Flash object, that should do the trick.

See this for an official Adobe guide to ExternalInterface: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f31

Answer (score -1):

Hey Man I am Laughing on me on answering this question in foolish way but you can do it this way. do you know how much seconds your intro plays? if yes do this:
Suppose Your Intro is of 10 Seconds:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("INTRO_DIV").delay(10000).hide();
$("body").delay(10500).fadeIn();
});
```

I added 500 milliseconds more so that your intro can be properly finished.

Comment: Not a good idea... there's no guarantee that the animation will load before the delay kicks in... the Flash "clock" won't necessarily be in sync with the DOM "clock." MUCH safer to have the Flash call a javascript function when it's done.